# Can Jupyter Notebooks be used to write Python codes

Tags: python

I am a new joiner to the platform of **Python** programming and I am learning its basics but before I start the real code I have a question. My friend suggested to should use Jupyter Notebook for coding so can it help me to code in Python?

Thank You!

Comment: You can write code in jupyter cells. If you need the .ipy file is just export that.

Comment: read this blog for basic introduction to jupyter notebook https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/getting-started-with-jupyter-notebook-for-python-4e7082bd5d46

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Jupyter Notebook can be used to run and write Python, and I would recommend having a look at this [guide](https://realpython.com/jupyter-notebook-introduction/) to help you get started.

Having said that, for beginners, I would suggest [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb), since it is very similar in style to Jupyter Notebooks, but has a much more gradual learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Jupyter notebooks are useful when you are not designing a big system, but you are performing a task where it is important to control the flow of the data and their transformation.
For big systems such as videogames, or web application using a jupyter notebook would just be impossible.
I would suggest you try both and use the one you are most comfortable with.

You can see some pros and cons here:

https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-Python-Jupyter-versus-a-normal-Python-development-environment

Answer (score 0):

Jupiter Notebook is a web based IDE used mostly for data science, ML etc.
So in short the answer is: yes
But it really depends on what you are working on